# Android how to set the layout the same size of an imageview programmatically

Tags: android, android-layout, android-imageview, android-image, android-image-capture

I have two imageView size an relativelayout. Both images will be loaded programmatically and I want to set the size of the relativelayout equal to the size of imgBackground. How can I do that? I tried the following and it didn't work. The layout appears to be much larger than the imgBackground.

```
imageLayout.getLayoutParams().width = imgBackground.getWidth();
imageLayout.getLayoutParams().height = imgBackground.getHeight();
```

Here's the code for the layout

```
<RelativeLayout
     android:id="@+id/imageLayout"
     android:layout_width="wrap_content"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     android:background="@color/black">
  <ImageView
       android:id="@+id/imgPhoto"
       android:layout_width="wrap_content"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
       android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
   />

  <ImageView
       android:id="@+id/imgBackground"
       android:layout_width="match_parent"
       android:layout_height="match_parent"
   />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/imageLayout"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imgBackground"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imgPhoto"
            android:layout_alignBottom="@id/imgBackground"
            android:layout_alignLeft="@id/imgBackground"
            android:layout_alignRight="@id/imgBackground"
            android:layout_alignTop="@id/imgBackground"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:scaleType="center" />

    </RelativeLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```